# Write permission denied while chmod showed 666

Tags: php

```
<?php
$file='test.txt';
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4).'<br>'; //666
if(is_writable($file)){echo "$file is writable";} //test.txt is writable
$stream=fopen($file,'a+'); //!ERROR denied access
fwrite($stream,'Hello World/n');
fclose();
?>
```

The only flag that is not causing an error is `fopen($file,'rb')`, so I believe I have read permission, but when I use chmod and it shows the file has read and write permission. Maybe something I have missed or misunderstood, thank you in advance.

Comment: perhaps check the permissions of the directories in the path

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, and you were right about the directories. We didn't have root permission and we couldn't change because the way it was set up.